# Is it possible to reference values of the hashmap a function is stored in using Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Let us say we had something like this:

```
(defstruct test :val :func)

(defn create-test 
  [] 
  (struct test 2 #(A)))
```

Is it somehow possible to reference :val from inside the provided function (that is, where A is located)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Given an object, it is not generally possible to find which other objects reference it. Since Clojure maps and functions are immutable, you must first create the function and then the map, so there is no way for the function to access the map unless it is somehow passed the map after it is created.

However, assuming that you can create the function after the other value, you can allow the function to directly access the value (but not the containing map) using a [closure](http://clojure.org/about/functional_programming#_first_class_functions):

```
((:function
  (let [value 2
        function #(str "The value is: " value)]
    {:value value
     :function function})))
;=> "The value is: 2"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of the problem of cyclic references; [lazy definitions allow the construction of these](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot).

While Clojure's approach here isn't quite as elegant as the linked Haskell version, [`promise`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/promise) allows you to put a lazy reference to the function in the map and then define the function to the compiler in an environment in which the map and its values are accessible:

```
(def knot-tying
  (let[{:keys[val func] :as knot} {:val "foo" :func (promise)}
       f (fn[](str val "bar"))]
    (deliver func f)
    knot))

((deref (:func knot-tying))) ;;=>"foobar"
```

Or if you prefer tying "in the other direction" and having the function use `deref` instead of having to `deref` it:

```
(def knot-tying-2
  (let[knot (promise)
       f (fn[] (str (-> knot deref :val) "bar"))
       tied {:val "foo" :func f}]
    (deliver knot tied)
    tied))

((:func knot-tying-2)) ;;=>"foobar"
```

Comment: But then the value in the map at `:func` is not a function; it's a promise.

Comment: Added a variant where the `:func` uses `deref` and not the user.